# ASP.NET Core 2.1 RC1 Extension on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

Now that we have the Go Live license, I'm trying to get my ASP.NET Core 2.1 app up and running on Azure but the extensions are still the old ones.

[image]

Has anyone been able to get an ASP.NET Core 2.1 RC1 app running on Azure? Any idea when the RC1 extensions will be available?

UPDATE:

Just checked my app on US West and looks like RC1 is now pre-installed in that data center.

[image]

Comment: Aiming for next week.

Comment: So my only option at this time is to do a self contained publish, correct?

Comment: Either that, or I guess hack up a site extension based on the Preview extension, and then replacing all the binaries with RC1.

Comment: BTW, I don't think they will release an extension for RC1. Instead, it'll be pre-installed on the VM.

Comment: I'll do the self contained publish. Had a ton of issues with it during preview-2. I'm hoping now that this is a bit more stable with go live green light, it should work without any headache.

Comment: I'm on the App Service side, so I can comment on deployment there, but I'm the wrong guy for Core 2.1 issues :)

Comment: We had the same problem and decided to downgrade our webapp to preview2 before rc1 will be available (either as an extension or included in app service)

Comment: I can't go back to Preview-2. I had nothing but issues publishing it to Azure. The app was fine but I simply could not run it on Azure App Service.

Comment: Unfortunately, a self-contained deployment is not an option for us because we use run-from-zip for our app services.

Comment: It's now in West US 2. If you're able to give it a quick try with your code in a test app, that would be great, and would help us validate that all is well :)

Comment: I'm in West US data center. Please let me know when deployment hits West US and I can test it for you. I did a self contained deployment and my app is working nicely. I'd be happy to test it with the runtime coming from the platform.

Comment: Does anybody know the schedule of upgrading Azure app services to .NET Core RC1 on different Azure locations?

Comment: They've already started and looks like they'll keep going till it's available on all data centers. As of this morning, I see RC1 pre-installed in US West which is where my app is -- see update in original post. My response is not the official response but I wouldn't be surprised if it's installed in all data centers pretty quickly.

Comment: I see RC1 in East US, however, i still cannot get an app targeting RC1 to run in the azure app service, and also was never able to get preview2-final to run either.  Does this installation work for apps that are not deployed as self-contained?

Comment: @spacebed I'm able to run my RC1 app using what's already installed on App Service, though it appears the only runtime installed is x86. So I might still do a self contained deployment to run my app on x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core 2.1 RC1 is now fully deployed to App Service. See https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/107. Also, if you run into a specific issue, you can use https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements-discussions/issues/47 to report it by [sharing at test repo](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-git-repo-to-report-an-issue).

Comment: Thanks. My app's been running on pre-installed runtime in US West since this morning. Though it appears, only x86 is available through App Service. Am I right about that?

Comment: @Sam you are correct about x86. Some related discussion on https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements-discussions/issues/47